# IDictionary<String, List<OpenXmlCompositeElement>> - get the List<OpenXmlCompositeElement>?

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm working with Open XML & I have a `IDictionary<String, List<OpenXmlCompositeElement>>` structure. I want to work with the List part of the structure but this.map.Values tries to wrap it in an ICollection.  How can I get the List part from my structure?

```
    public List<OpenXmlCompositeElement> MapData()
    {
        //this does not work
        return this.map.Values;
    }
```

Comment: which one? there could be more than one.

Comment: Just use the key to access the one you want. Or loop through the dictionary? `List<OpenXmlCompositeElement> list = dictionary["key"];`

Comment: yes, I finally got that there are multiple lists:).  This finally gave me what I was looking for:  test=dynamicContent.MapData().Any(l=>l.Any(i=>i.Descendants().OfType<Drawing>().Count()>0));  I needed to determine if my List of Open XML Elements had any images in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a dictionary, it expects you to tell from which key you want the value.

So this would be the code you need, where `yourKey` is the key you want to retrieve:

```
public List<OpenXmlCompositeElement> MapData()
{
    return this.map["yourKey"];
}
```

If you have no interest in the key, and the dictionary is just a dictionary because the serializer says so, you could get the first item for example like this:

```
public List<OpenXmlCompositeElement> MapData()
{
    return this.map.Values.First();
}
```

Comment: this.map.Values.First() gave me what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can either loop through the dictionary and use the value you would like, or access the List directly using the key (in this case it's a string)

```
IDictionary<String, List<OpenXmlCompositeElement>> myDictionary;

List<OpenXmlCompositeElement> myList = myDictionary["myKey"];
```

Where `myKey` is available in the dictionary.

Alternatively you can loop through

```
foreach (var item in myDictionary)
{
    var key = item.Key;
    var value = item.Value

    // You could then use `key` if you are unsure of what
    // items are in the dictionary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your dictionary...

```
IDictionary<string, List<OpenXmlCompositeElement>> items = ...;
```

Get a specific List by key...

```
List<OpenXmlCompositeElement> list = items["key"];
```

Get the first list in the dictionary...

```
List<OpenXmlCompositeElement> list = items.Values.First();
```

Concatenate all lists in the dictionary into a single list...

```
List<OpenXmlCompositeElement> list = items.SelectMany(o => o).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<OpenXmlCompositeElement>> kvp in IDictionary)
    {
    string key = kvp.key
    List<OpenXmlCompositeElement> list = kvp.Value;
        foreach(OpenXmlCompositeElement o in list)
        {
         Do anything you need to your List here
        }
    }
```

I am working with dictionaries as well, so here is a real example that I am currently working with:

```
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<DataRecords>> kvp in vSummaryResults)
        {
            string sKey = kvp.Key;
            List<DataRecords> list = kvp.Value;
            string[] vArr = sKey.Split(',');

            int iTotalTradedQuant = 0;
            double dAvgPrice = 0;
            double dSumQuantPrice = 0;
            double dQuantPrice = 0;
            double dNumClose = 0;

            foreach (DataRecords rec in list)
            {
                if(vSummaryResults.ContainsKey(sKey))
                {
                    iTotalTradedQuant += rec.iQuantity;
                    dQuantPrice = rec.iQuantity * rec.dInputTradePrice;
                    dSumQuantPrice += dQuantPrice;
                    dAvgPrice = dSumQuantPrice / iTotalTradedQuant;
                    dNumClose = rec.dNumericClosingPrice;

                }

                else
                {
                    vSummaryResults.Add(sKey, list);
                    //dNumClose = rec.dNumericClosingPrice;
                }
```